# IFTTT Filter code for Pinterest RSS feed

Tags: javascript, typescript, rss, ifttt

I am using IFTTT to post to Facebook page from pinterest RSS.
Here is the url of RSS Feed - [Link](https://in.pinterest.com/rushmegoin/funny-humor-memes.rss/)

What I want to do is replace all 236x string with 564x in the RSS feed result.
As **I am not a programmer** I wrote this code to replace 236x with 564x in Javascript .

```
var url=Feed.newFeedItem.EntryImageUrl;
var newurl=url.replace(/236x/g,'564x');
```

[image: Editor code]

But it seems it is not working can any one help me with proper filter code for IFTTT in Javascript , TypeScript.
***Thanks in advance.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FacebookPages.createPhotoPage.setPhotoUrl()` action to override the url field :

```
var url = Feed.newFeedItem.EntryImageUrl;
var newurl = url.replace(/236x/g,'564x');
FacebookPages.createPhotoPage.setPhotoUrl(newurl);
```

Note that you have a list of all available functions for the specified services at the right of the filter code window